# Unexpected result from Knapsack problem recursive function

Tags: c

I have to write a simple program to solve the Knapsack problem.
I wrote this code for now and I think this is all I need, but I keep having different results everytime I execute it. All I can think is that there is a problem of memory deallocation, but I don't know how to solve it. Any ideas?

P.S. Maybe it's a stupid question but I never worked in C.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int max(int a, int b){
  if(a > b) {
    return a;
  } else {
    return b;
  }
}

int knapsack(int prices[], int weight[], int n, int max_weight){
  if(n < 0)
    return 0;
  if (weight[n] > max_weight)
    return knapsack(prices, weight, n-1, max_weight);
  else
    return max(knapsack(prices, weight, n-1, max_weight), (knapsack(prices, weight, n-1, max_weight - weight[n]) + prices[n]));
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int i, weight[] = {2,3,3,4}, prices[] = {1,5,2,9}, max_weight = 7, n, result;
  for (i=0; i<argc; i++) {
    printf("%d: \"%s\"\n", i, argv[i]);
  }
  n = (sizeof(weight))/(sizeof(weight[0]));
  result = knapsack(prices, weight, n, max_weight);
  printf("%d\n", result);
  return 0;
}
```

**RESULTS**
[image]

Comment: `weight[n]` is not defined

Comment: @Ôrel Oh yeah sure... I need more coffee. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are indexing the arrays with an number that is too large.
You get the size of the array doing

```
n = (sizeof(weight))/(sizeof(weight[0]));
```

You cannot index weight at `n` because it only has indices `0` to `n-1`

Try calling

```
result = knapsack(prices, weight, n-1, max_weight);
```

Comment: Yeah that was the problem, it was right in front of me, I’m so stupid! @Orel showed me the error in the comment section